# C++ check if empty line

Tags: c++

If input is empty line output "0".
I can't use string only char, is it possible?

```
char liczba[20];   
cin>>liczba;  
if (liczba!=NULL) { cout << "0"; break; }
```

does not work for me

Comment: `liczba!=NULL` will always be true, because `liczba` is not a pointer.

Comment: You are correct, the above will not work, for at least two reasons (with the second reason being that a large line will result in memory corruption, undefined behavior, and a crash). To answer your question, yes, it is possible to do so correctly in every case, simply by reading input one character at a time, and counting how many characters were read before a newline gets read.

Comment: You mean: `if (strlen(liczba) == 0)`.

Comment: because in my code i use commands concerning on char

Comment: My code: In this task i converting Roman numbers to Arabic ones and the condition is that if the empty line is output 0 and I can't do it
https://pastebin.com/TVWvnxNf

Comment: Might also want to init liczba with 0's. 

`char liczba[20] = {0};`

Comment: warning:  `cin>>liczba;` will read one whiespace-delimited token from `cin`. If there is only one token on that line, groovy. If there is more than one token on the line, you should look into using one of the variants of `getline`. And probably a longer array (or `std::string` when allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check `if (liczba[0] == 0) { ... }`, or `if (*liczba == 0) { ... }`

This checks if the first character in the string a null terminator. If the first character is null, the string is empty.

Here's a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char message[80];

    std::cout << "Give me some input!" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> std::noskipws >> message;

    if (*message == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "There's nothing there!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Thank you, that's helpful.\n";
    }
}
```

The [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) tells the stream to treat whitespace as any other character, so you can get empty lines.

Comment: Probably because the stream extraction operator doesn't return until it finds something to extract.

Comment: I swapped char for string
https://pastebin.com/16TTrm73
when I use $string s; getline(is, s); if (s.empty())$ for empty code, it works, but mine doesn't

Comment: noskipws works but the only problem is that while interrupts me
while (cin >>noskipws >>liczba, !cin.fail())  after 1 lap always breaks whether an empty line or not

Comment: if anyone else wants to help me with this% @! the task, I noticed when it prints the length of the entered character in turn, when the line is empty, the program completely ignores it at the beginning, that it will not even display its length or anything related to it